# WPF: create a slow movement slider

Tags: wpf, slider

I need to create an slow slider, so if the user moves too fast, the slider will just try to reach the mouse slowly. Like a lowpass filtered movement.

I need that because the slider affects the power in an engine that shouldn't change too fast.

I'm new to data binding but I bind two ways with my property and it works. So I would like to keep on using this slider without re-coding too much stuff.

I tried grabbing the ValueChanged, check if the difference between the old and the new value was too big, but then I cannot edit the e.NewValue (it just exposes Get, not set)
I tried setting the slider.Value in the ValueChanged with my new value, but it leads to stackoverflow (I guess due to the binding that retrofeeds the change)

I also tried with the Thumb_DragDelta, but again, I can see the values, but cannot set the new (smaller) delta.

Any clues ???

---

**EDIT**
I entered the code that controls the max increase in the Set part of the affected Property (the binded one) As a result the increases actually get slowed down BUT, the updates only happens if you move your mouse, if you drag too fast, so the thumb stay back and you stop moving the mouse, the thumb does not follow you. If you click moving your mouse the thumb comes to your mouse.

I guess this is because the value changed is only called when DragDelta happens and it only happens onMouseMove ..

Any workarounds ?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this is an alternate solution.

A slider that lags behing the cursor seems very strange to me. UX-wise, It would give the impression the application is lagging rather that the increase is happening gradually. Personally I would create a usercontrol with a disabled slider and two repeatbuttons. This could look something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="25">
    <RepeatButton Click="ButtonLess_Click" Content="less"/>
    <Slider Width="200" IsEnabled="False" Name="Slider1" ></Slider>
    <RepeatButton Click="ButtonMore_Click" Content="more"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

code behind:

```
    private void ButtonLess_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Slider1.Value = Math.Max(Slider1.Minimum, Slider1.Value - Slider1.SmallChange);
    }

    private void ButtonMore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Slider1.Value = Math.Min(Slider1.Maximum, Slider1.Value + Slider1.SmallChange);
    }
```

[image]

This way you cannot slide the slider itself, but clicking/holding down "less" or "more" increases or decreases the slider gradually.

Comment: this would definitelly work, but is not what I was looking for. The design is exactly what I explained, you can drag wherever you want but it will only move as fast as the engine can actually change the power. Thanks for the code sample anyhow